# Django automatically logouts when page reloads

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-sessions

I use SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True for logging out the user once browser closes and it works fine in local computer but when I deploy the site and use this feature it immediately logouts the user once I login.
I am using heroku as deployment server.

Session settings in Settings.py :-

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1000
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True 
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

Comment: What cache have you configured on Heroku? Unless you actually have a functional cache then the session will never be saved.

Comment: How to change cache configuration on heroku?